# How does the Windows File Explorer Quick Access recent items feature work?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I'm not talking about pinned items here, but the "recently opened" items that show up below those. I say "recently opened" because I assume that's *supposed* to be the case, but it's not for me. Let me explain further with a screenschot:

[image]

As you can see, I have four "recent" folders listed here. But the last time that I *actually* opened *any* of those folders is well over a month ago; 6 months or more for some!

Ideally I'd like to have a maximised File Explorer window's entire height filled with Quick Access items, with the really important ones being pinned as they already are, and the rest of the space filled with dynamically ever-changing folders, based upon what I've been opening most frequently in the past month or so. Is this possible to achieve?

As an aside, I'd also like a detailed explanation of how Windows chooses what folders to display here. Anyone knowledgeable enough to give me that would be my hero! MTIA :-)

Comment: This list has to be manually filled by you, there is nothing done automagically. You can e.g. drag&drop folders or files into this section. Another option is via context menu of files & folders "Append to Quick Access" (or a similar menu entry).

Comment: Uh...I don't know what you've been smoking, coz drag/drop doesn't work for this, and there is no "Append to Quick Access" option in my context menu. There is "**Pin** to Quick Access", but no prizes for guessing what that achieves! :P And re: your "automagically" comment: this section of Quick Access was **not** created by me; it has been evolving on its own ever since I last installed Windows. It's only recently that Windows has seemingly stopped updating it. So while I appreciate you trying to help, your comment is so beyond wrong that I feel a little embarrassed to have to tell you that!

Comment: @Robert, that is incorrect. There is a setting that controls whether recent files and folder do or do not get placed into Quick Access.

Comment: @Kenny83 I am not sure how or why you see "Pin to Quick Access" as "permanent". That IS the method of manually placing items into Quick Access, and right-clicking on them again gives you the option to remove them from Quick Access. Further, please note that only a single question is allowed per post. You need to edit your post to make it a single question, rather than the 4ish it currently contains.

Comment: @music2myear *sighs* I knew people were sure to misinterpret what I want here...I'm talking about the non-pinned section, the dynamic section that is highlighted with a red rectangle in the screenshot. You do seem to know what I'm talking about, since you mentioned above a Windows setting that controls the appearance of this section (which I'd love to know the location of if you're aware). Thanks for your help! :-) I'll try to rephrase the question to condense it a little.

Comment: Sighing is easily interpreted/misinterpreted as being rather passive aggressive, and rather out of place for a semi-professional QA site such as this. I would recommend against expressing that. I have edited my answer below addressing further information I have just now researched and learned. Please note that nearly everything I found and answered below are the result of two simple internet searches.

Comment: Finally, we cannot answer the detailed explanation of how the algorithms work to populate this list. That is proprietary information and Microsoft has either published it, in which case you have as easy access to it as we do, or they haven't, in which case we can only guess, and guesses are not authoritative answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick Access** is a virtual folder that presents two *JumpLists* in a folder view --- *`Frequent`*`folders` and *`Recent`*`files`.

Jumplists are most commonly seen when you right-click on a Taskbar icon.
[image]

The best overview of their behavior I found is [this MS article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#jump-lists).

> By default, a standard Jump List contains two categories: recent items and pinned items, although because only categories with content are shown in the UI, neither of these categories are shown on first launch. Always present are an application launch icon (to launch more instances of the application), an option to pin or unpin the application from the taskbar, and a Close command for any open windows.

...

> The results used in the destination list are calculated through calls to [SHAddToRecentDocs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shaddtorecentdocs). Note that when the user opens a file from Windows Explorer or uses the common file dialog to open, save, or create a file, SHAddToRecentDocs is called for you automatically, which results in many applications getting their recent items shown in the destination list without any action on their part.

...

> An application can define its own categories and add them in addition to or in place of the *`standard Recent and Frequent categories`* in a Jump List. The application can control its own destinations in those custom categories based on the application's architecture and intended use.

Jumlists are implemented via the [.NET JumpList class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?view=net-5.0).

> You cannot access the shell's Jump List directly or read its contents into the JumpList class. Instead, the JumpList class provides a representation of a Jump List that you can work with, and then apply to the Windows shell. You typically create a JumpList and set it one time when the application is first run. However, you can modify or replace the JumpList at run time.

So it's the code that implements the JumpList class that creates and maintains the data files found in:

- **`shell:Recent\AutomaticDestinations`**
- **`shell:Recent\CustomDestinations`**

( Either of the above can be pasted into the **Explorer** Address bar to navigate to these normally hidden folders. )

---

So, with all this in mind, the behavior you're seeing is most likely due to one of two causes:

- The **`f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms`** file has become corrupted
- The folders you see are somehow being accessed in a way that adds them to the jumplist, but the folders you access freqently aren't. ( For example, `.txt` files created via **PowerShell** don't appear in the `Recent files` list until they opened in **Notepad** or another registered app )

If your `Frequent folders` list has been static for months, the first is the most likely cause. To fix this, you simply need to delete the file, re-start, and *patiently* wait for the jumplist to rebuild itself.

If you're curious, you can examine the data stored in the file using [NirSoft's JumpListView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html) utility. With that, you could see the raw set of folder paths the jumplist is using.
[image]

(Default view modifed to position `ApplicationID` column immediately following `FileName` column and sorted by `ApplicationID`. )

Creating a new folder in **Explorer** creates a corresponding entry in Explorer's jumplist ( ID: `f01b4d95cf55d32a` ).

Saving a text file from **Notepad** to the new folder updates the folder's entry in `Explorer's` jumplist and also adds the file to `Notepad's` jumplist (ID: `9b9cdc69c1c24e2b`) and the `Recent files` jumplist (ID: `5f7b5f1e01b83767`).

[SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can be used to track file operations in the `AutomaticDestinations` folder.

Comment: Now **this** is more like what I was hoping to find out! TYVM for the extremely comprehensive answer! I think I might reinstall Windows over the weekend (it's about time anyway; I usually do a clean install every 6 months or so just to keep things fresh) and hopefully that will get me back to the way I remember things working, and the way you describe. Cheers! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the feedback and for marking my reply as 'Answer'.

Answer (score 1):

First, this only applies on a personally-owned computer. If you are working on a business-owned computer, policies may be applied that may or may not modify the system's Quick Access settings and behaviors.

Next, the primary controls for whether Quick Access is automatically populated or not are found in the File Explorer > View tab > Options > Folder Options dialog > General tab > Privacy section. There you can choose whether Files or Folders are automatically added to Quick Access or not, along with a button to clear the recent files and folder lists. Note that this control does NOT control whether recent files and folders are recorded, only whether those recorded files and folders are viewable in Quick Access.

Then, you can find the Quick Access virtual folder in the file system at the path `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items`, but you cannot modify this folder directly. It appears to be a conglomeration of two *real* folders `.\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` and `.\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations` which are likely the actual Pinned vs Automatically selected item folders. I do not know how to modify these as they do not contain .lnk files. I'd guess there may be utilities to handle this, but I haven't done this research, as, I suspect, you haven't either.

You will note that this folder contains items even if you've told your system not to show recent items in the Quick Access view.

Finally, to manually add a file or folder to Quick Access you right-click on that file or folder and select **Pin to Quick Access**, and to remove an item so pinned, you right-click and select **Remove from Quick Access**.

Comment: I guess we just see things differently. By "permanently" I meant that a pinned item shows up at the top of Quick Access, and will always stay there until you remove it. The non-pinned section, in my prior experience, changes as the Recent Items folder changes. It's always been 4 items long for me, and if Windows could tell that I'd opened Folder A x times in the past y days, as compared to Folder B's z amount of opens in that time (where x < z), then Folder A would be replaced with Folder B. Or maybe **I'm** the one who's been smoking funny stuff haha :P Anyway thanks for the info :-)

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic, but the word "permanently" does not mean what you are explaining. Using clear language is absolutely necessary to correctly convey what is in your mind, and thus required in order for us to answer the question you actually have, rather than the question that you imagine in your head. I understand what you mean, and the edits to answer above indicate that what you are seeking is not possible based on the information I have, and the information I was able to add to my knowledge just now by searching.

Comment: My apologies for wasting your time and many thanks for doing my research for me. I did try to search Google with a few different phrases before asking here, but came across countless results talking about the pinned items section, hence my confusion and frustration that led to the passive-aggressive sigh. I apologise for that too, and hope that I didn't waste too much of your time. But for what it's worth, I didn't expect you or *anyone* to research this for me; rather I was hoping for a MS expert who already knew to come across this post. Anyway thanks again for the info and your patience :-)

Comment: I don't consider it a waste of me time, do not worry about that. I would not have answered if that were the case, and I know more about this tool than I did before I began answering your question. SuperUser is not an official Microsoft forum. Microsoft has official support forums, though what you appear to actually be looking for is a feature request. I don't believe they'd see any reason to divulge how they build these list, which items supersede others, etc. I've always assumed it was based on a "number of visits over a given amount of time, compared", but I have nothing besides a feeling.

Comment: > I've always assumed it was based on a "number of visits over a given amount of time, compared" - me too! Hence my confusion and why I started this whole debate lol. But you gave me enough info to do more research on my own, so thanks again. You're probably right that any MS employee or MVP would not want to divulge this info, or allow it to be changed, but it's worth a shot right? :P And yeah I know this isn't an official MS forum; just hoped that some MVPs might be on here and might know and be willing to share. Anyway thanks for the stimulating convo and have a great day!