# How do I keep programmatic shortcuts visible in Recent Items?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, shortcuts, recent-items

Using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/836818/1218303), I can create shortcuts (.lnk files) for various executables and folders.

When I use the **Recent Items** directory (`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`) in the `SHORTCUT`, the `PWS` call creates the shortcut, but it disappears from **File Explorer** quickly - too quickly to register in an **Open**/**Save** dialog.

Strangely, the file still exists; I see it in the output of `dir`, and creating a new shortcut manually using [these steps](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17456-create-recent-items-shortcut-windows-10-a.html#option2) adds (2) to the file name used in the **Shortcut** tab of its **Properties** window. Similarly, creating the shortcut on the **Desktop** first, then copying it to the **Recent Items** folder, will prompt you for an overwrite. The copies disappear too, so this isn't a workaround either way.

How do I prevent the programmatic shortcuts from disappearing from the **Recent Items** folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you can use notepad to open a `.lnk` file, and it will get added to quick access automatically:

```
C:\> notepad "%userprofile%\Desktop\Microsoft Edge.lnk"
```

**However**, you can't really add a shortcut `.lnk` file itself to quick access or recent items. The reason is that file explorer will *parse* the `.lnk` and only add the actual target to the "Recent Items" list. The example above adds this to the recent items:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
```

And does not include any additional info like arguments or initial directory

---

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` is a virtual folder that does not really exist. As soon as Explorer recalculates the contents, files like the icon you created stop showing up. Explorer stores the actual "Recent Items" information in files named `<id>.automaticDestinations-ms` within hidden folders: `\Recent\CustomDestinations` and
`\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`.

These are used and updated by each application's **jumplist** (where you can right-click notepad's icon and see a list of recent files for example).

Take a look through the answer here for a more detailed explanation of how the Recent Items directory works: https://superuser.com/a/1670209/673426.

And here is detailed MS documentation for jump lists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist

Comment: thanks for the answer - I wasn't aware of virtual folders before, so I think I'll do some digging on them.

interestingly, the first few times I went to **Recent Files**, I didn't see those **Destination** folders.  Now, **Recent Files** is showing up as **Recent**, and I see those folders.  Moreover, applications that normally use **Recent Files** in the Open/Save dialog now use **Recent**, and the shortcuts I created there are showing up.

Comment: Yep, `\Recent Items` is just a display name that Explorer overlays for `\Recent`. I'm not sure if "Recent Files" is just an en-GB difference or if you're looking at a different application. Depending on how you access the folder, explorer may alter more or less of what you see